# KNMI MSGCPP geoview to WGS84

Tags: convert, wgs84, image, geos

I would like to transform KNMI MSGCPP geoview netCDF file to WGS84 netCDF file with gdal_translation and gdalwarp. I got error msg.

I shared the geoview netCDF file (140 MB):  https://z001.s3.amazonaws.com/test.nc

```
szabot@XSRV:/mnt/c/gdal/bin/gdal/apps$ gdal_translate -a_srs WGS84 NETCDF:"test.nc":cldmask test001.nc
ERROR 5: OSRCalcInvFlattening(): Wrong input values
Input file size is 3712, 3712
Warning 1: Several drivers matching nc extension. Using NETCDF
0...10ERROR 5: OSRCalcInvFlattening(): Wrong input values
ERROR 5: OSRCalcInvFlattening(): Wrong input values
ERROR 5: OSRCalcInvFlattening(): Wrong input values
ERROR 5: OSRCalcInvFlattening(): Wrong input values
...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```